# Basicity of singlet and triplet carbene

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Which form of n-heterocyclic carbene is more basic and stable? ( Singlet or triplet)

Answer (score 0):

Singlet carbene is sp2 hybridised whereas triplet carbene is sp Hybridised. More s character, more nuclear force, more Electro negativity so more acidic hydrogen and hence less basicity.

So singlet carbene is more basic.